# Copy byte array to Go struct accounting for struct padding

Tags: go, struct, padding

Suppose I have this C struct

```
struct Foo
{
    uint8_t a;
    // 3 bytes of padding
    uint32_t b;
}
```

And its equivalent in Go:

```
type Foo struct {
    a uint8
    b uint32
}
```

And I have a byte slice that contains the C struct:

```
data := []byte { 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 }
```

What is the best way to get that data into the Go struct (and vice versa).

Note that I *do want padding* according to the normal C rules. The C struct is *not packed*.

For packed structs I could do something like this:

```
    data := []byte { 0x01, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 }
    f := Foo{}
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(data)
    err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &f)
```

What is the equivalent, taking padding into account?

Comment: There is no guarantee there will be a specific padding. And that is apparently not related to C.

Comment: You must serialize and de-serialize if you don'y want to pack your structs.

Answer (score 1):

Ah I realised there is a relatively simple way to do it - just explicitly add dummy padding bytes into the Go struct:

```
type Foo struct {
    a uint8
    _ [3]byte
    b uint32
}
```

Then you can use `binary.Read()`

Comment: `[3]byte` needs `_`, but that will fail. Then, it would be:`type Foo struct {
 a uint8
 _ [3]byte
 b uint32
}` :-)

Comment: Oh yeah that's weird. I read about anonymous fields but didn't realise they only work for non-primative types.